Apache Pulsar Go Client created unexpected producer/consumer
I have a Go application which tests sending and receiving messages through Apache Pulsar and deploy them within the same Kubernetes cluster, as follows:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/apache/pulsar-client-go/pulsar"
)

var client pulsar.Client

func produceHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Create a producer
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "producing message...")
    producer, err := client.CreateProducer(pulsar.ProducerOptions{
        Topic: "public/default/test",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Send a message
    msg := pulsar.ProducerMessage{
        Payload: []byte("hello"),
    }
    msgID, error := producer.Send(context.Background(), &msg)
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to publish message", error)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Published message {", string(msg.Payload), "} with id ", msgID)
    producer.Close()
}

func consumeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Create a consumer
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "consuming message...")
    consumer, err := client.Subscribe(pulsar.ConsumerOptions{
        Topic:            "public/default/test",
        SubscriptionName: "sub",
        Type:             pulsar.Exclusive,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Consume message
    msg, err := consumer.Receive(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Received message {", string(msg.Payload()), "} with id ", msg.ID())
    consumer.Ack(msg)

    // Clean up
    if err := consumer.Unsubscribe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    consumer.Close()
}

func main() {
    // Initialize a Go client
    var error error
    client, error = pulsar.NewClient(pulsar.ClientOptions{
        URL:               "http://pulsar-broker.pulsar.svc.cluster.local:8080",
        OperationTimeout:  30 * time.Second,
        ConnectionTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
    })
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Could not instantiate Pulsar client: %v", error)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    fmt.Println("Started server on :9090")

    http.HandleFunc("/produce", produceHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/consume", consumeHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
}

It works as intended as I followed the guide to have one consumer listen to the topic, and let one produce publishes a message. The unexpected behavior happens when I hit the "/produce" endpoint twice, and then hit "/consume" once. This should create two producers and one consumer. However, the logs show that as soon as I create the consumer, another producer is being created, which ends up with three producers and one consumer.
root ➜ /app $ go run main.go 
Started server on :9090
INFO[0004] Connecting to broker                          remote_addr="pulsar://pulsar-broker-0.pulsar-broker.pulsar.svc.cluster.local:6650"
INFO[0004] TCP connection established                    local_addr="10.244.0.59:44710" remote_addr="pulsar://pulsar-broker-0.pulsar-broker.pulsar.svc.cluster.local:6650"
INFO[0004] Connection is ready                           local_addr="10.244.0.59:44710" remote_addr="pulsar://pulsar-broker-0.pulsar-broker.pulsar.svc.cluster.local:6650"
INFO[0004] Connected producer                            cnx="10.244.0.59:44710 -> 10.244.0.47:6650" epoch=0 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0004] Created producer                              cnx="10.244.0.59:44710 -> 10.244.0.47:6650" producerID=1 producer_name=pulsar-0-58 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0004] Closing producer                              producerID=1 producer_name=pulsar-0-58 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0004] Closed producer                               producerID=1 producer_name=pulsar-0-58 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0065] Connected producer                            cnx="10.244.0.59:44710 -> 10.244.0.47:6650" epoch=0 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0065] Created producer                              cnx="10.244.0.59:44710 -> 10.244.0.47:6650" producerID=2 producer_name=pulsar-0-59 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0065] Closing producer                              producerID=2 producer_name=pulsar-0-59 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0065] Closed producer                               producerID=2 producer_name=pulsar-0-59 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0191] Connected producer                            cnx="10.244.0.59:44710 -> 10.244.0.47:6650" epoch=0 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0191] Created producer                              cnx="10.244.0.59:44710 -> 10.244.0.47:6650" producerID=3 producer_name=pulsar-0-60 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0191] Closing producer                              producerID=3 producer_name=pulsar-0-60 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0191] Closed producer                               producerID=3 producer_name=pulsar-0-60 topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0192] Connected consumer                            consumerID=1 name=iljwa subscription=sub topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0192] Created consumer                              consumerID=1 name=iljwa subscription=sub topic="persistent://public/default/test"
INFO[0192] The consumer[1] successfully unsubscribed     consumerID=1 name=iljwa subscription=sub topic="persistent://public/default/test"

I then checked with pulsar-admin. It shows that for the first two produces, there are two messages delivered and no message consumed, which is correct. But as I add in a consumer, it shows there are three messages delievered and three messages consumed, and it really confused me.
I tried switching message type between "shared" and "exclusive", but it didn't work.
